# SweetAlerts - Load Once

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am wondering if there is a way to load a SweetAlert ONCE, with a cookie. I have tried multiple methods and they have not worked mostly because I am a newbie. Here is my code without the cookies...

--

```html
<script>
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/sweetalert.css">
#test


<body>


  <script>
swal({
  title: "District Closed",
  text: "Severe snow is causing major accidents and is unsafe for our students and staff. The district is closed including schools & offices, updates will be posted here. This popup closes fifteen (15) seconds after loading the page or clicking the status button.",
  timer: 15000,
  type: "error",
  showConfirmButton: false
});
</script>

</body>
```

(The code above will not work if you run the snippet as the files pertaining to SweetAlerts are hosted on my own site)

Comment: I'm assuming you are asking to show the alert if the cookie doesn't exist first?

Comment: Yes, I am. - - - - - -

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage property of the window

Local storage alert item value is 0 then show sweet-alert

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var swal_alert = localStorage.getItem("alert");

        if(swal_alert != 1){
            swal({
                title: "District Closed",
                text: "Severe snow is causing major accidents and is unsafe for our students and staff. The district is closed including schools & offices, updates will be posted here. This popup closes fifteen (15) seconds after loading the page or clicking the status button.",
                timer: 15000,
                type: "error",
                showConfirmButton: false
            });
        }

        localStorage.setItem("alert", "1");

    });

</script>
```